# Как получить рандомный array и его значения и только его значения если он находиться ещё в одном масиве?

Tags: javascript

Взгляните на строчку this.color она на данный момент получает рандомный цвет из всех масивов. Как можно получить только одну палитру цветов. Но рандомную каждый раз.

```
var firstColor =[
'#147CA6',
'#2CA4BF',
'#4ACAD9',
'#4AD9D9',
'#CEF2F2'
];
var secondColor = [
'#FFE2DF',
'#FFD6DC',
'#F5C1C7',
'#E8A0AB',
'#E8707B'
];
var thirdColor = [
  '#FFEE00',
  '#FFC200',
  '#FF9D00',
  '#FF7700',
  '#FF4800'
];
var colorArr =[ firstColor, secondColor, thirdColor];
function Circle(x,y,radius,color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 25;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
    this.color = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)][Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];

    this.update = function(){
    this.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, что подразумевается под словом палитра?
Палитра на сколько я понимаю это несколько цветов 
  '#FFEE00',
  '#FFC200',
  '#FF9D00',
  '#FF7700',
  '#FF4800'

в функции Circle()

this.color - подразумевает один цвет из палитры одного из трёх массивов 

нужно только из одного из трёх предложенных? или как?

Comment: Ну смотри есть 3 массива firstColor secondColor thirdColor. Я хочу что бы один из трёх масивов выбирался. И ипользывал только цвета этого массива. На примере. Есть выьираеться например рандомно thirdColor и в нём есть вот такие цвета #FFEE00',
  '#FFC200',
  '#FF9D00',
  '#FF7700',
  '#FF4800'   У меня есть например 10 кружочков который будут принимать рандомно только эту палитру цветов. Надеюсь так понятней